# Close the terminal window after doing something

Tags: python, subprocess, call

I want to just print some information and call an application e.g. notepad.

```
from subprocess import call
print("Opening Notepad++")
call([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"])
exit()
```

Problem now is that the terminal window doesn't automatically close. It stays open until I close the notepad window. How can I make the terminal window disappear automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Popen` like so

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe', \
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, creationflags = 0x08000000)
```

Comment: It worked after adding  "PIPE" on line 1 and removing "subprocess" from line 2

Comment: what do "stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False" do here

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the reason they weren't working was because the import was wrong, it should be fine now

they are merely commonly used arguments, you can read a detailed explanation in the documentation here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You could use pythonw.exe:
pythonw script.py

Or change its extension to `pyw` e.g. `script.pyw` and double click on it.

If you do that you should print *"Opening Notepad++"* to a popup window. See: [Python Notification Popup that disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084839/python-notification-popup-that-disappears)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the notepad command with `start COMMAND`, like in Linux we use `COMMAND &` to fork the process into the background. in windows we use the `start COMMAND`

So you code refactored:

```
from subprocess import call
print("Opening Notepad++")
call([r"start C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"])
exit()
```

*Although note I don't have a windows machine to test on.*